# Java. Connect to server using FTPClient class

Tags: java, string, ftp, int, ip

I try to connect using FTPClient class. This code runs perfectly:

```
client.connect("172.20.5.131");
```

But I can not connect when ip address looks like `-1406991772`. How can I sole this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: convert int to InetAddress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957637/java-convert-int-to-inetaddress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, First you have to convert the integer value of IP-Address into a valid IP-Address using [`InetAddress#getByAddress(byte[])`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByAddress%28byte%5B%5D%29) :

```
int ipAddress = -1406991772;
byte[] bytes = BigInteger.valueOf(ipAddress).toByteArray();
String address = InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes).getHostAddress();
```

and then pass the `address` to `client.connect(address);`

Comment: Ankit Lamba, but my `ipAddress` is not integer, it is String. How can I convert it?

Comment: sorry for late response, using `Integer.parseInt(ip_address)`